# Django path to current page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django template page, and want a link from this page, containing current URL, for example, I am on */article/11* and want link to */article/11/remove*
I tried the following construction:

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}remove">Remove article</a>
```

But I get link to */article/remove* instead of */article/11/remove*
However when I change it to

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}">
```

I get link to */article/11*

How can I get URL not trimmed?

Comment: Also, can you post the actual output? Just what the `<a>` tags actually look like when they're rendered would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it doesn't point you to /article/11remove, which is what it sounds like it should do, but either way, you're missing a slash. Try `<a href="{{ request.path }}/remove">` instead.

However, that's really not the right way to do it. You shouldbe using {% url 'name_of_remove_view' %} to get the url, not assuming it's going to be wherever you are plus `/remove`.

**Edit**: In that case, your problem is probably that {{ request.path }} is not outputting anything at all. That would explain why just having "remove" would take you to /article/remove, and having "" would take you to where you currently are, due to the way that relative URLs work. You might want to make sure that you have a request object at all in your template environment.

Comment: when I try `<a href="{{ request.path }}/remove">` I get link to simply _/remove/_, but when I try to use `{% url 'viewer.views.remove_article' %}` I get TemplateError trying to access _/article/11_. In urls.py I have the following `(r'^admin/edit_article/(?P<article_id>\d+)/remove$', 'viewer.views.remove_article'),`. Rendered tags look exactly as I wrote: `<a href="/remove">Remove article</a>`

Comment: Thanks! It was really no request object